# How to see when "svn up" was issued to update to a given revision

Tags: svn, logging, history, svn-update

Is it possible to check when in time a file/working copy was updated locally to a specific revision (i.e. even if local files got overwritten by say further revision updates)?

Comment: one could alias `svn` to catch and log `up` commands. or set history to log timestamps `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "` and regularly grep for `svn up`. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `svn up` updates **Working Copy**, not repository
2. No, you can't check it (at least internally in svn), except checking timestamp of file (with `use-commit-times` disabled)

Comment: thanks, corrected wording. checking timestamp of file would only give time for last svn up but not for already overwritten ones; would like to know about older revisions, though. cheers.